# How to circumvent ‘Option clash for package …’ error?

Tags: package-options

I use a package `foo` that requires a package `bar` with some options. Now, assume that I need `bar` to be loaded with a different set of options. Unfortunately, when I try to load `bar` myself I usually end up with an `Option clash for package bar` LaTeX error. Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{foo.sty}
\ProvidesPackage{foo}
\RequirePackage[noisy]{bar}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{bar.sty}
\ProvidesPackage{bar}
\DeclareOption{noisy}{\PackageWarning{bar}{I'm noisy}}
\DeclareOption{silent}{\PackageWarning{bar}{I'm silent}}
\ProcessOptions*
\end{filecontents}

%% \usepackage[silent]{bar}

\usepackage{foo}

\usepackage[silent]{bar}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In an ideal world, the LaTeX message `Option clash for package …` simply indicates an error and, as such, should not be ignored, but entail appropriate measures. Nonetheless, I’ve made the experience that, in reality, there are situations where it is either harmless or even advantageous to circumvent this error. Versatile tools for this purpose are `\PreventPackageFromLoading` and `\ResetPreventPackageFromLoading` from the [`scrlfile`](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf) package. Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{foo.sty}
\ProvidesPackage{foo}
\RequirePackage[noisy]{bar}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{bar.sty}
\ProvidesPackage{bar}
\DeclareOption{noisy}{\PackageWarning{bar}{I'm noisy}}
\DeclareOption{silent}{\PackageWarning{bar}{I'm silent}}
\ProcessOptions*
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{scrlfile}

\PreventPackageFromLoading{bar}

\usepackage{foo}

\ResetPreventPackageFromLoading

\usepackage[silent]{bar}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why don't you simply put `\PassOptionsToPackage{silent}{bar}` before `\documentclass{article}`?

Comment: @HarishKumar: See my comments on the answer given by Daniel E. Shub.

Answer (score 2):

What about declaring `silent` as a global option with `\documentclass[silent]{article}` and then just using `\usepackage{bar}` in your document. The silent option will still be loaded because of the global option.

Comment: This only works if the `silent` and `noisy` options complement each other, but doesn’t work if they are conflicting in some way.

Comment: @mhp In that case you really have a clash. Hopefully the `bar` package is well enough designed to handle requests for conflicting options. The `foo` package should not be loading the `bar` package with options that it doesn't require.

Comment: If you are lucky … ;-) In my experience, there are nowadays quite some opportunities where it is advantageous to outsmart the LaTeX2e option system.